# Two column text with image in middle middle

Tags: html, css

I have looked around a lot but cannot find a tutorial or suggestion for how to place an image in both the vertical and horizontal center of a page of two-column text. I've seen explanations for straddling an image across two columns, but aligned at the top of the text. I want to align an image in the middle middle.!

Is this even possible? I would prefer to do it in CSS, but will consider anything that works, (especially if it comes with some instruction.) 
Thanks for any help you can offer (even if it's to tell me to give up.) (c;

Comment: Please, show us what have you tried or considering trying. Also, show us your HTML so we can better understand your particular case.

Comment: Never give up. Write some code. Post it, and we'll help.

Comment: Here's the idea: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53073/two-column-text-with-circular-insert However, I want to insert a square image, not a circular one. So that should be even easier, right? I am refraining from posting my feeble attempts at coding as they are so far away from what I want that they could only make things more confused. Thanks again for pondering this.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the technique described [here](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) and shown below to be very effective:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="//placehold.it/200x200">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.container:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%; 
  vertical-align: middle;
 }

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you looking for.

1) Create two div (as column) and put image at the middle(Image will overlapped the both column.)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nvc9h/3/)

```
 img
 {
 background: red;
 height: 300px;
 width:400px;
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 }
```

2) Create 2 div(as column) with opacity:0.5 and put image at the middle (The image will acts like background since z-index is added)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kP99M/2/)

```
img
{
z-index:-1;
}
```

Good Luck!!

Comment: Yes, that puts the image where I want it. But I want the text to flow around the image with about 30px of padding on all sides.